Uncaught (in promise) Error: TypeError: Instance of '_JsonMap': type '_JsonMap' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' Flutter
I was trying to display the result of API in listview.
THe API Link is https://dummyjson.com/products
But the same code worked with the data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
Why does this happen?
class ApiExamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ApiExamplePageState createState() => _ApiExamplePageState();
}

class _ApiExamplePageState extends State<ApiExamplePage> {
  List<dynamic> _data = [];
  List<dynamic> data1 = [];

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://dummyjson.com/products'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        _data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        print("JSON DATA : $_data");
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('API Example'),
      ),
      body: _data.isEmpty
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = _data[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(item['products']['title']),
                  subtitle: Text(item['products']['body']),
                );
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}


You used wrong type _data.
Try this approach.
class ApiExamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ApiExamplePageState createState() => _ApiExamplePageState();
}

class _ApiExamplePageState extends State<ApiExamplePage> {
  List<dynamic> _data = [];
  List<dynamic> data1 = [];

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://dummyjson.com/products'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        _data = jsonDecode(response.body)['products'];      <======= made change here.
        print("JSON DATA : $_data");
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('API Example'),
      ),
      body: _data.isEmpty
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = _data[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(item['products']['title']),
                  subtitle: Text(item['products']['body']),
                );
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}

